# java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:3000

Tags: java, http, httpclient

I build a http server with `http://sparkjava.com/` that validate files, if it is valid or not.

The code is very simple:

```
post("/pdf", (req, res) -> {

            if (req.headers("application/pdf") == null) {
                res.status(400);
                PdfState state = new PdfState();
                state.SetIsValid(false);
                return JsonUtil.toJson(state);
            }

            InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(req.bodyAsBytes());
            PdfState state = pdf.validate(stream);
            res.type("application/json");
            return JsonUtil.toJson(state);

        });
```

Then I want to write a unit test and choose the http client library http://square.github.io/okhttp/.

The test function looks as follow:

```
public void IsPdfContentRequestValid_StreamValidPdfContent_ExpectJsonSuccess() throws Exception {

        File file = new File("/Volumes/Dev/java/inspector/files/pass.pdf");

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://127.0.0.1:3000/pdf")
                .addHeader("Content-type", "application/pdf")
                .post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN, file))
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

        System.out.println(response.body().string());

    }
```

When I run the test, it complains:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:3000
```

What is wrong with OKClient?

**Update**

That is the whole error:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /Users/developer/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2016.2/temp-testng-customsuite.xml
0    [Thread-1] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log  - Logging initialized @1554ms

java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:3000

    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:189)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.buildConnection(RealConnection.java:173)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:193)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:129)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:98)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:124)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:170)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:60)
    at com.cloudfirmation.inspector.controller.PdfControllerTest.IsPdfContentRequestValid_StreamValidPdfContent_ExpectJsonSuccess(PdfControllerTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:746)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1264)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1189)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1104)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1076)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

56   [main] INFO  spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer  - >>> Spark shutting down ...
56   [main] INFO  spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer  - done

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

I think the server is running when start the test.

Comment: Just to make sure: is your server up and running when you start the test? Does it respond when you open it in your browser?

Comment: After you start your server program, run `netstat` to verify that it is actually listening to port 3000. In Windows, run `netstat -ano | findstr 3000`.

Comment: Or telnet to port 3000 and see if it connects, and even better telnet to port 3000, then type "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n" (without the quotes and using the Enter key instead of \n of course.)  It should give you *something* back.